# wireless adapter drivers and utility software

Tags: networking, drivers

I just purchased a realtec wireless adapter that came with drivers and utility software---When installing drivers, It also installed the utility software which aparintly takes control of the adapter  I can see the network but it won't let me log on.  I'm running windows 7, is there any way that I can let windows take control of the adapter, such as in windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall the utility software. When you visit *Programs and Features* sort the items by date installed. You'll either see two new entries (driver + utility) or just a single item. If you see a single item right click on it and see if it has a "modify" option on the context menu.

If this does not work, you can also try uninstalling all of the software that you just installed. You'll now see your wireless adapter is flagged in *Device Manager*. Go to its dialog and choose to update the drivers. When it asks, say to choose location for the driver software and select the DVD drive (check search sub directories). This will search the disk for just the drivers and avoid the utility. This may not work however if they've packed the drivers into an installer. If this is the case you'll need to see if you can extract the installer with 7zip or other compression software.

Good luck!